# How can I access HDInsight Blob Storage from C# Mapper?

Tags: c#, hadoop, mapreduce, azure-hdinsight

I have a "Hadoop on Windows" cluster with blob storage (`log-container` at `logfstore`) as default storage configured (input and output is read and written from/to there).

I'm using the MapReduce SDK to write and manage mapper and reducer in C#.

How can I access other files on the blob storage from within my C# code?

### I tried the following:

1. `File.ReadAllLines(@"/log100by10/Input/filelist_short.txt");`

   Result: Could not find a part of the path 'c:\log100by10\Input\filelist_short.txt'
   exception
2. `File.ReadAllLines(@"log100by10/Input/filelist_short.txt");`

   Result: Could not find a part of the path 'c:\apps\temp\hdfs\nm-local-dir\usercache\admin\appcache\application_1453123456785_0006\container_1453123456785_0006_01_000002\log100by10\Input\filelist_short.txt'
3. `File.ReadAllLines(@"wasb://log100by10/Input/filelist_short.txt");`

   Result: The given path's format is not supported
4. `File.ReadAllLines(@"wasb://log-container@logfstore/log100by10/Input/filelist_short.txt");`

   Result: The given path's format is not supported

### The whole mapper looks like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Hadoop.MapReduce;

namespace AzureTest.MultiTest
{
    class MultiTestMapper : MapperBase
    {

        public override void Map(string inputLine, MapperContext context)
        {
            string path = @"/log100by10/Input/filelist_short.txt";
            try
            {
                string[] text = File.ReadAllLines(path);
                context.EmitKeyValue("****input ",text[0]);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                context.EmitKeyValue("****error ", ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the same way you normally would, see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/

Comment: the account connection string is part of the config you get from the context.

Comment: Thanks, Thomas. My understanding is that HDInsight maps the blob storage as local file system, so I would be able to directly access it via wasb: scheme. Wouldn't I massively loose performance, when accessing it via an external http address?

Comment: HDI doesn't map anything as a local filesystem! Blobs (using the wasb protocol) replace HDFS, so underneath it will go to the external http address anyway. Even in Java you'd need to do a RPC call to the `FileSystem`.

Comment: Thomas, I'd love to follow your suggestions. But unfortuantely I can neither find the connection string in the context (it just offers InputFilename, InputPartitionId, EmitKeyValue, EmitLine, IncrementCounter and Log), nor can I call CloudStorageAccount.Parse. When doing the later, the job fails, even though I call Parse inside a try/catch clause. I suspect I somehow need MRRunner to upload Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll for me?

Comment: Difficult, C# MapReduce is implemented via Streaming, so sadly some stuff might not be available and adding dlls is a pain. Maybe someone from the HDI team can help you more on that, you can always file a support ticket :)

Comment: You could also pass your stroage account info in as a defines...-Defines @{"fs.azure.account.key.$fullAccountName"=$wantedAccountKey}

Comment: Thomas, I finally got it working the way you proposed in your first comment. I just had to use Costura.Fody to embed all the required dependencies into the executable. Will you post your link as answer, so I can accept it?